# regular expression - replace dot if not between two numbers and not in text list

Tags: regex, preg-replace

How would a regular expression looks like if it should replace `. [dot]` with `[.</p></p>]` but not if the . is between numbers or in a list of texts.

The text list could be:

- fx.
- acc.
- misc.

(more will come - when I finds them)

EDIT:

The problem is I have some texts like `"Hello.World"` or `"I'am in paradise.The paradise is nice"` but I actually found 1 thing, which might be easier.

Split the text if the letter after the . is capital, that should actually do it.

I think this something like this

```
return preg_replace('/\.([A-Z]{1})/', '.</p><p>$1', $text);
```

It can properly be optimized more.

Comment: Include your sample input/output in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.$)\.|(?=^\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*)\.
```

You can try this.This covers all the options.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kO7lO2/5